# Error while Set up SharePoint Framework development environment (Cannot find package 'mem-fs')

Tags: npm, sharepoint, yeoman

I am a beginner in SharePoint, and when I set up the SharePoint Framework development environment, I installed all the prerequisites mentioned in the official Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#install-nodejs). PFA
[image]

But when I run yo command I am getting below attached issue (**Cannot find package** `'mem-fs'`) please help :

[image]